# Ping from vbs script the value of a variable

Tags: variables, vbscript, ping

I am trying to make a simple script that will ping a machine that it gets as argument.

When the VBScript is executed, it seems that it does not recognize the variable as a variable, it just take it as string information and prints the following error message;

> Ping request could not find host Var2. Please check the name and try again.

Below is the script:

```
Dim Var2

Var2 = inputbox("What is your B number?")
Wscript.Echo Var2

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k ping Var2"
```

By searching on the web I was getting much longer script solutions for what I believe should be something not so complicated.
Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `Var2` as a string to the command. To add the content of `Var2` to the command, you have to concatenate the strings in your last line:

```
objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k ping " & Var2
```

Comment: Perfect.
Double quotes correct, it takes it as a string.
Thanks.

Comment: [What is the difference between VBScript's + and & operator?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1208912)

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for the remark. I updated my answer.